# How to unset a view variable in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How is it possible to unset a view variable in a controller? Is there an inverse of the function `$this->set()`?

Comment: Do you mean set it to null?

Comment: No, it is not about PHP. It's about CakePHP. When I set a variable to be rendered in the view I use `$this->set('name', 'value')`. The question is how to undo this.

Comment: Did you try this? `$this->unset('name')`

Comment: Yes. No function with this name.

Comment: Can You describe Your idea? You can not use it

Comment: Martin, would you please add some extra source code to your question? Where from exactly are you trying to unset that variable?

Comment: More importantly: Why are you unsetting it (or trying to) in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

While I don't see a reason to do this, have fun with unsetting $this->viewVars['whatever'].

https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.View.ViewVarsTrait.html#$viewVars